# How to handle query string in Asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 website. I have used action link while designing table to display a list of data. while navigating from that action link I have passed a class object as a parameter. After visiting that link, it parses that object parameter as long query string which exposes data in the URL.


What is the way to handle a query string in MVC? 

Is it possible to hide query string or way to pass an object as a parameter without exposing it in the URL?

Comment: No you can't. Only an option is Encryption

Comment: @CoolJK if you're sending data from the browser, encryption of the data is useless because the encryption code, and any keys used, will be visible to anyone who inspects the source code of the page in their browser tools. Unless you're talking about using HTTPS? That doesn't remove the data from the querystring though, it can still be logged by a webserver, but it does (largely) stop it from being MITM'd on the journey. HTTPS plus a POST request with data in the request body instead of the querystring is probably the most sensible option.

Comment: @ADyson how can i do using HTTPs?

Comment: by setting up your webserver correctly to serve the site over HTTPs and getting a valid SSL certificate for it. It's not a task you do within the application code itself. You don't really need to do this in your localhost or testing environments particularly, but certainly you should do it for the live version of your site.

Comment: what is the  RouteValueDictionary? will it be helpful in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can not hide the query string, it is part of the URL. You could encrypt it tho.

One solution would be to use a POST request instead of a GET. Then you can send the data in the body of the request, it will not show up in the URL. But it will still be accessible if you inspect the network traffic (e.g. if you run [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) on the client computer).

Another solution would be to still use a GET request, but instead of passing all the data, just pass an ID, then load the data again from the database using this ID. Note that this ID can be spoofed too, so make sure the User has actually the permissions to request this ID.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Show details", "Details", "Data", new { dataId = Model.Id })

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Details(long dataId) {
    var data = _dbContext.Data.Find(dataId);
    var vm = new DataDetailsViewModel(data);
    return View("Details", vm);
}
```

Comment: might be worth also suggesting use of HTTPS to encrypt the connection, if it isn't being used already, so that the network traffic can't be sniffed so easily.